# No data holes between raster mosaic elements in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, merge, mosaic, esri-ascii-raster

I have several ASCII grid files (ARC/INFO ASCII GRID format). All with the same 32 bit floating point pixel type and 5 m resolution. I want to merge this files to the one file with 5 m resolution. I have made mosaic file. Unfortunatelly on the edges some of the mosaic elements there are tight holes with no data pixels.

[image]

Should I do IDW interpolation?

Comment: Replace them by focal statistics  mean

Comment: Are you trying to do this using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Focal Statistics to fill the noData gaps.

```
Con(IsNull("raster"), FocalStatistics("raster", NbrRectangle(5,5, "CELL"), "MEAN"), "raster")
```

https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000004792

Comment: Great! It is exactly this what I need! Thanks a lot!